# Dynamically Create Table With Javascript and Jquery for each entry in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm doing a async ajax django post that returns a list of vms with properties. I can't seem to get the HTML format to format correctly. It doesn't draw the tables with the styles, it just outputs the text, and I can't see the output because the debugger either didn't receive it or its hiding it.

**this is what my console output looks like**

```
            <div id="table_name"></div>





          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "/vmstatus/", 
                    type : "POST",
                    dataType: "json", 
                    data : {
                        selected_customer : $("#selected_customer").val(),
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                        },
                        success : function(json) {
                            console.log('Good');

                            for (index = 0; index < json.vmlist.length; ++index) {
                                if(index < 0){
                                    document.getElementById('table_name').innerHTML = "<table class='sortable table' id='table-data'><thead><tr><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''> <b>VM Name</b></th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''><b>PowerState </b> </th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='N'><b>Commands </b></th></tr></thead><tbody>";                                                                            
                                }else{
                                    document.getElementById('table_name').innerHTML = document.getElementById('table_name').innerHTML +'<tr><td>'+ json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td>' +json.vmlist[index][1] + '</td><td>' +json.vmlist[index][2] + '</td></tr>';
                                }
                            }

                            console.log( 'Server Response: ' + json.server_response + json.vmlist);
                        },
                        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                            console.log('Bad');
                            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                        }
                });
                return false;
        });
    });
```

sorry for the long text I didn't know if I could put it in () and make it multi line.

Thanks to Tom I was able to get it working, but I have to make one last tweak, I'm writing an if statement to draw an image in place of index[1] for on or off. However it just always draws the on. The three possible values are poweredOn poweredOff or suspended I need to draw an image for all three states.

```
var on = '<img src={% static "icons/on2.jpg" %}>'

var off = '<img src={% static "icons/off.jpg" %}>'

console.log('Good');
$('#table_name').append("<table class='sortable table' id='table-repeat-data'><thead><tr><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''> <b>VM Name</b></th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''><b>PowerState </b> </th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='N'><b>Commands </b></th></tr></thead><tbody>");
for (var index = 0; index < json.vmlist.length; index++) {
    if(json.vmlist[index][1] = 'poweredOn'){
        $('#table-repeat-data').append ('<tr><td>' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td>' + on + '</td><td>' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '</td></tr>');
    }else{
        $('#table-repeat-data').append ('<tr><td>' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td>' + off + '</td><td>' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '</td></tr>');
        }
}
```

So all I have yet to figure out is how to get the sorter to work.
http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/ is the sorter I used.

Also,
I dynamically update the information. I dynamically assign vmlist[2] position which is a vmid to that dynamic id to the tds, i want to empty the tds and refill as it loops through the information. Here is my code but the problem is the console out puts the following:

```
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery-1.10.2.js:5375
"Good" vmstatus:40
"update!" vmstatus:51
```

this is when it calls the first update:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...).empty is not a function vmstatus:85
"Good" vmstatus:73
120

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "/vmstatus/", 
                        type : "POST",
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data : {
                            selected_customer : $("#selected_customer").val(),
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                            },
                            success : function(json) {
                                setInterval(update, 5000);  
                                var on = '<img src={% static "icons/on2.jpg" %}>'
                                var off = '<img src={% static "icons/off.jpg" %}>'
                                console.log('Good');
                                $('#table_name').append("<table class='sortable table' id='table-repeat-data'><thead><tr><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''> <b>VM Name</b></th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''><b>PowerState </b> </th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='N'><b>Commands </b></th></tr></thead><tbody>");

                                for (var index = 0; index < json.vmlist.length; index++) {
                                    if(json.vmlist[index][1] == 'poweredOn'){
                                        $('#table-repeat-data').append ('<tr><td id=' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '>' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td id=' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '>' + on + '</td><td id=' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '>' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '</td></tr>');
                                    }else{
                                        $('#table-repeat-data').append ('<tr><td id=' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '>' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td id=' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '>' + off + '</td><td id=' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '>' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '</td></tr>');
                                    }
                                }

                                console.log( 'update!');
                            },
                            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                console.log('Bad');
                                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                            }
                    });
                    return false;
            });
        });
function update(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "/vmstatus/", 
                        type : "POST",
                        dataType: "json", 
                        data : {
                            selected_customer : $("#selected_customer").val(),
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                            },
                            success : function(json) {
                                var on = '<img src={% static "icons/on2.jpg" %}>'
                                var off = '<img src={% static "icons/off.jpg" %}>'
                                console.log('Good');
                                for (var index = 0; index < json.vmlist.length; index++) {
                                    if(json.vmlist[index][1] == 'poweredOn'){
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][2]).empty();
                                        $('#table-repeat-data').append ('<tr><td id=' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '>' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td id=' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '>' + on + '</td><td id=' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '>' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '</td></tr>');
                                    }else{
                                        document.getElementById(json.vmlist[index][2]).empty();
                                        $('#table-repeat-data').append ('<tr><td id=' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '>' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td id=' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '>' + off + '</td><td id=' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '>' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '</td></tr>');
                                    }
                                }

                                console.log( 'update!');
                            },
                            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                console.log('Bad');
                                console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                            }
                    });

}        

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code, try this instead:

```
function isPowered(string) {
    var onImg = '<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"/>';
    var offImg = '<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>';
    return (string == 'poweredOn') ? onImg : offImg;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table_name').append("<table class='sortable table' id='table-data' data-sortable><thead><tr><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''> <b>VM Name</b></th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title=''><b>PowerState </b> </th><th align='center' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='N'><b>Commands </b></th></tr></thead><tbody>");

    for (var index = 0; index < json.vmlist.length; index++) {
            $('#table-data').append ('<tr><td>' + json.vmlist[index][0] + '</td><td>' + isPowered(json.vmlist[index][1]) + '</td><td>' + json.vmlist[index][2] + '</td></tr>');
    }

    Sortable.init();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/x4afd4zm/3/)

**ALSO**: You will want to re-initialize any javascript AFTER the table is built for things like tooltips and sortable, etc.

Comment: also my sorting class is no longer being applied to that table

Comment: class='sortable table' is how i call the sortable function and the bootstrap design.

Comment: got the if statement to work but not sure how to re instantiate the sortable.

Comment: Which sortable are you using?

Comment: sortable.js   that is literally the name [link] http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/ [/link]

Comment: Also I'm trying to update dynamically but for some reason it won't asign the ids ill post it up as well

Comment: Oh you are using a different sortable... Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/x4afd4zm/2/) using [THIS](http://github.hubspot.com/sortable/api/options/) sortable ;)

Comment: Here is the image stuff you are looking for: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/x4afd4zm/3/)